# Creating a minipage in multicolumn with a figure and a parallel text gives no parallel text

Tags: minipage, multicol

My book consists of many line of multicolums and I am well used to it since text and figures are in different lines. Now adding a comment instead of a figure, I wanted to use a minipage and this fails with the simplest MWE: I am sorry I missed some crucial lines in the MWE

```
\documentclass[ngerman,12pt,a4paper]{book}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{babel,multicol}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\begin{document}
        \multicolumn{4}{@{}p{12cm}@{}}{
        \noindent
        \begin{minipage}[t]{0.5\textwidth}
            {\includegraphics[width=5.4cm]{example-image-a}}
        \end{minipage}
        \begin{minipage}[t]{0.4\columnwidth}
            \lipsum[1]
        \end{minipage}}
    \\
    
\end{document}
```

Second assay:

```
\documentclass[ngerman,12pt,a4paper]{book}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{babel,multicol}
\usepackage{lipsum,longtable,graphicx}
\begin{document}
    \begin{longtable}{@{}p{5.9cm}@{}p{1cm}@{\hspace{3mm}}p{5.9cm}@{}p{1cm}@{}}
    
        \multicolumn{4}{@{}p{12cm}@{}}{
            \noindent
            \begin{minipage}[t]{0.5\textwidth}
                {\includegraphics[width=5.4cm]{example-image-a}}
            \end{minipage}
            \begin{minipage}[t]{0.4\columnwidth}
                \lipsum[1]
            \end{minipage}
        }
    \end{longtable} 
    
\end{document}
```

Comment: multicolumn can only be used inside a tabular.

Comment: What's a "second assay"? A "second attempt"? Please calarify.

Comment: Ulrike: i omitted the longtable environment in the first version. 
Mico: attempt is correct. This MWE at least compiles.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe this is what you are looking for:

```
\documentclass[ngerman,12pt,a4paper]{book}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{babel,multicol}
\usepackage[export]{adjustbox}% for valign
\usepackage{lipsum,longtable,graphicx}
\usepackage{showframe}% alignmrnt tool
\begin{document}
    \begin{longtable}{@{}p{5.9cm}@{}p{1cm}@{\hspace{3mm}}p{5.9cm}@{}p{1cm}@{}}
        \multicolumn{4}{@{}p{12cm}@{}}{
            \begin{minipage}[t]{0.5\hsize}
                \includegraphics[width=5.4cm, valign=t]{example-image-a}
            \end{minipage}\hfill
            \begin{minipage}[t]{0.4\hsize}
                \lipsum[1]
            \end{minipage}
        }
    \end{longtable} 
    
\end{document}
```